# Is the use of the word "compelled" correct in this context?

Tags: word-choice

Does "Is it **compelled** with a good story/plot?" work well with the chosen word (compelled)? Or am I misusing it (If so, what's a better alternative)?

Comment: *Compelled* means forced. *Compelling* means fascinating. So the former doesn't work **well** in your example, so yes, you're misusing it.

Comment: @deadrat is almost certainly right, but we need to know what it is you're actually trying to say. *Compelled* is probably wrongly used here, but we can't know for certain if you don't provide you me intended meaning.

Comment: You might be thinking of "propelled", which means "moved forwards".  So someone might say "The film is **propelled** by a fast-moving narrative" for example.

Comment: "Impelled" may be intended, too. Hard to say as written.

Comment: Or, for that matter, the question could be trying to say something like "Did you find yourself compelled by the plot?" which would generally be worded more like "Was the plot compelling?".

Comment: For the sake of @Hope: "In the context, it sounds misused. Also, the definition of the word does not match up. Just a suggestion, but it could also be reworded for a clearer meaning."

Comment: I know I'm a bit late on this, but thanks everyone!

Answer (score -2):

It doesn't sound orthographically correct. You could use "Intrigued" instead.

> Is it intrigued with a good story/plot?